# Correct/best datastructure for storing columnar data with custom metadata

Tags: python, parquet, hdf5, h5py

I have medium sized tabular datasets (some entries are categoricals or custom strings). I want to store these (perhaps with HDF5/parquet?) and have the following features:

- Concurrent reading
- Compression (Snappy or whatever works well)
- Store metadata (eg a set of column headers, the type of each column as a string and a boolean for each column). Right now I can store the first as a set, the second and third as a dictionary.

HDF5:

I can store the metadata as pickles in an HDF5 file and the dataset either as a dataset or each column as one dataset with chunking. Something like:

```
data = {"col1": [0.15, np.nan, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55],
        "col2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "col3": [1, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan]}

values = pd.DataFrame(data).to_numpy()

with h5py.File("test_set.h5", "w") as fp:
    fp.create_dataset("column headers", data=[pickle.dumps({"col1", 
                                                            "col2", 
                                                            "col3"})])
    fp.create_dataset("column type", data=[pickle.dumps({"col1": "regression", 
                                                         "col2": "classification", 
                                                         "col3": "classification"})])
    fp.create_dataset("column sparsity", data=[pickle.dumps({"col1": True, 
                                                             "col2": False, 
                                                             "col3": True})])
    fp.create_dataset("data", data=values,
        **hdf5plugin.Blosc(cname='snappy', clevel=9, shuffle=hdf5plugin.Blosc.SHUFFLE))
```

Parquet:

This is better due to row/column access optimisations, but doesn't seem to allow for easy addition of metadata (I might be wrong!)

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, but you know pandas supports writing and reading HDF5 and parquet natively?

Comment: Yep I do, my question is more how to store the dataset along with metadata in a clean pythonic manner.

Comment: Don't confuse code with data schema. "Pythonic" is a code style (PEP-8 and 20), and has nothing to do with the data. A good schema organizes your data in a logical way (so it's easy to write and use/access). I am not aware of a "pythonic" definition for data schema.

Comment: Right that makes sense. I was more thinking about the consequences of a schema in terms of interaction with the datastructure. In the sense that some datastructures seem more conducive to naturally writing Pythonic code vs ones where you have to painfully wrangle to do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with pandas or pickles, so don't completely understand what you are trying to do. I created an example based my interpretation of your code and data. It has the following steps:

1. Creates a numpy record array with your data, then writes it to a dataset named "column headers".
2. Adds the "column type" data as attributes to the dataset; 1 for each column (attributes are a good way to save metadata)
3. Adds the "column sparsity" data as attributes to the dataset; 1 for each column

I created the dataset with gzip compression, using the smallest compression level. Compression is a trade-off of size on disk vs I/O time. This level works well without creating a lot of I/O overhead. (Obviously with this small file there isn't any benefit.) You can benchmark these settings with your real data.

**Code:**

```
dt = [ ('col1',float), ('col2',float), ('col3',float) ]
recarr = np.recarray( (5,), dtype=dt)

recarr['col1'] = [0.15, np.nan, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55]
recarr['col2'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
recarr['col3'] = [1, np.nan, 3, 4, np.nan]

with h5py.File("test_set.h5", "w") as fp:
    ds = fp.create_dataset("column headers", data=recarr, 
                           compression="gzip", compression_opts=1)
    ds.attrs['col1 type'] = "regression"
    ds.attrs['col2 type'] = "classification"
    ds.attrs['col3 type'] = "classification"

    ds.attrs['col1 sparsity'] = True
    ds.attrs['col2 sparsity'] = False
    ds.attrs['col3 sparsity'] = True
```

Comment: Thanks, I only added pandas for illustrative purposes and pickle is Pythons library for serializing objects into a byte stream for easier saving to local disk and loading easily/natively. I had a similar idea to what you are writing, I am not sure how attributes work in HDF5. I'll have to have a read!